# Pass data Through segue not working in swift 3 any solution?

Tags: ios, segue, swift3

i have passed data from didselect method of `collectionView` like this

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let dicttemp = (arrRespProduct?.object(at: indexPath.row))! as! NSDictionary
        dicData = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dicttemp)

         performSegue(withIdentifier: GlobalConstant.segueIdentofier.productDetail, sender: self)
    }
```

But method

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

is not calling in swift 3... Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prepareForSegue` is changed in swift 3.0 so you need to write like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above answer you should expect a lot of changes of method names like: `prepareForSegue` to `prepare` or  `String.substringFromIndex` to `String.substring`. The obvious method name endings are ommited/moved to the label of 1'st argument.