# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am trying to make a sidebar. The following is the code for the rear menu. The extension MainViewController and UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate = self
is giving use of undeclared type and use of unresolved identifier respectively

```
import UIKit
class HomeVC: UIViewController {




@IBAction func menu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "openMenu", sender: nil)
}



var data : String = ""


@IBOutlet weak var welcome: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     welcome.text = data
}


}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MenuVC
{
    destinationViewController.UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate = self
}
}

extension MainViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, 
presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: 
UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return PresentMenuAnimator()
}
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is use of unresolved identifier....@Larme

Comment: `destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = self` ? And give the WHOLE Error message, it's usually explicit and had hints on where exaclty is the issue. My guess ? `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` is an unknown property of `destinationViewController`.

Comment: @NiravD this is not all about passing data through segue. Pls check question again. OP demanding Transition while pushing VC.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Thats why I just suggest, if I want I will directly mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @NiravD Both quest are different.

Comment: @nithinsampath Signature of `prepareForSegue` is changed in Swift 3 checked this one [Possible Duplicate of Pass data Through segue not working in swift 3 any solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533609/pass-data-through-segue-not-working-in-swift-3-any-solution)

Comment: @NiravD...still the build error exists....

Comment: @nithinsampath Edit your question with current code and error that you facing

Comment: sorry...@NiravD...what u suggested worked....i had an error on my part.... thanks for all your help....